# Cannot make HTTP requests between docker containers

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose

I have 2 apps running as services under docker-compose.

1. React App
2. Node.js server

**I am trying to make an HTTP request from my React app to the Node.js server by calling:**
`fetch("http://backend:4000/")`

I get `GET http://backend:4000/ net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED` in the browser when I access my React app under `http://localhost:3000`

This is my docker-compose file.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - "backend"

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
```

I'm running Ubuntu and I have been having this problem for ages. Nothing really helps - creating a network and assigning services to them, creating links and many others.

**One curious thing is that when I get into the React app container and I run bash command:**
`ping backend` or `curl http://backend:4000`, the request actually works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that, you are trying to connect your backend app through your browser not through frontend container. If that is the case, then you should reveal the backend port  like;

```
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    ports:  #whatever the port number
      - "4000:4000"
```

then you should change the url from http://backend:4000 to  http://localhost:4000 on your react app.

Comment: I made it work like this but it's a hacky way. 
I am not doing the fetch call from my browser, it runs inside it, but it's called from JS code inside React app. I saw this thing working under macOS. And it should work. By default, docker created the default network and links services under it.

Comment: React App is a client app running on your browser. Do you mean that there is another app running inside your frontend container and it is making calls to the backend container?

Comment: No, I have these 2 docker containers and I have one request going from one service (React app aka `frontend`) to another (Node aka `backend`). 

The js code that does the fetching is located inside `componentDidMount` method inside the `App.js` file in the react app. Shouldn't be the problem I guess.

Comment: @MihaiPerju  it is the problem. You are calling your backend container through your browser, not through your frontend container. Your frontend container is simply serving static files ( aka your react app). It is doing nothing but serving files(unless you are running an aditional node app in it). Code located inside `componentDidMount` is running on your browser. Therefore, you should expose backend port and change the url as i've stated above.

Comment: The problem with this happens when I want to do something more about it. 

Say for example create an `Nginx` service which will redirect my traffic to the react app, and then the React app will call the Node.js endpoints. 

In this case, I don't see how I should make it work with exposing the ports. 

Do you think of a cleaner way for this specific problem?

Comment: I got a workaround in the code, I will refer to `/api` instead of `http://backend:4000/api`. But yes, you are right.

Comment: @MihaiPerju You can hide your backend app behind an nginx container. If that's the case then you don't need to expose ports of backend container. Then you simply expose ports of nginx container, and connect your backend app from your react app through nginx. However, this is not the case in the docker-compose file you've shared.

Answer (score 0):

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - "backend"
    links:
      - backend

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
```

Incorrect option

```
links:
  - "backend:test"
```

`"backend:test"` is the reason you're getting a name resolution error.
That is not the service name, `backend` is.

Comment: Thanks, I just forgot to remove that as I tried many other options. Still doesn't work. I edited the question. 

Still, I am doing `fetch("http://backend:4000")`, I didn't refer to `test`

Comment: Did you try it with `links`?

Comment: Yes. I specified the link `backend:test` and did `fetch("http://test:4000")`. Doesn't work

Comment: Would it be helpful to create a git repo with my project and give a link?

Comment: Look at the answer  closer. You're specifying `backend:test` which is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, `links: -"backend:test"` should be `links: -backend`

Comment: Theoretically, if I can ping the backend server from the frontend server and also `curl` it, it's very strange that it doesn't let me do from inside the frontend app. Perhaps related to my OS? Ubuntu Disco